# Multiple substitution when repeating the previous command

Tags: bash, command-line, history-expansion

I know that I can simply substitute a string with another in the previous command by typing:

```
!!:gs/string1/string2/
```

But how I can perform multiple substitutions, e.g. having a command:

```
echo "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" > test1
```

I want to substitute `A` with `B` and `1` with `2`, so execute such a command:

```
echo "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" > test2
```

How can I do it with `!!` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" > test1
$ !!:gs/A/B/:s/1/2/
echo "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" > test2
```

That is, just add the second substitution to the end of the first.  Just be aware that the second substitution will act on the result of the first.